# Working with vi editor through script

Tags: shell, ksh

I am working with a Korn shell. There is  a log file which is continuously updating. I need to update this file and insert one character in it. I am writing a shell script for it. Can anyone suggest me how I can do it through script? I need to open and close that file using vi editor through script. Please suggest a way for it.

Here are the commands I use when I edit that file:
vi my_file 
Press ‘E/e’ (to start edit)
Press ‘i’ (to insert)
Press ‘F’ (to insert missing F)
Press:  Esc  ->  :  ->  wq!  ->  [Enter]  ->  y  ->  [Enter]*

I need to insert one F at the beginning of first line in this file. Please can anyone suggest me how I can do it through vi editor?. I cant use any other editor like 'sed' because that file is continously updating.

Comment: Instead of assuming that `vi` is the right tool for the job, why not describe the task in enough detail that folks can suggest something that *is* the appropriate tool?

Comment: "that file is continuously updating"? `vi` is no more atomic than `sed` is (though `sed -i` _does_ have some bugs of its own), so I don't know what problem you think you're solving.

Comment: ...if you have a file that's being changed by other processes, and you want to be sure that your changes aren't stomping on changes the other process wants to make, then you need to look at advisory locking -- and modifying the other process to do the same.

Comment: By "continuously updating", do you mean that another program has this file open all the time?  If so, then neither `sed` nor `vi` will do.  `vi` replaces the original file from a temporary one, but the program will still be updating the original.  The original will not go until the program closes.  If you did a `vi` you will now loose all the updates that the program did (assuming the program has not locked the file).  Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`vi` is a "visual" editor. It's intended to be used interactively, by a human looking at a terminal and entering commands; that's what "visual" means.

---

The script-driven equivalent to `vi` is `ex`. (Often, `ex` is actually provided by your `vi` package, or even the same executable).

If you can write something in `vi`'s command mode that will do what you want, you can feed that as a script to `ex`.

---

An example, tested against Apple's BSD `ex`:

```
ex -c ':open filename-to-edit' -c '1s/^/F/' -c ':wq'
```

An example tested against the `ex` shipped with `vim`:

```
ex -s filename-to-edit <<'EOF'
1s/^/F/
:wq
EOF
```

Alternately, without using `vi` or `ex` at all:

```
tempfile=$(mktemp)
{ printf %s 'F'; cat filename-to-edit; } >"$tempfile"
mv "$tempfile" filename-to-edit || rm -f "$tempfile"
```

Comment: Can you suggest me the code how I can use "ex"? With a code block.

Comment: @user286009, I've provided an example, such as it is. Since you want to use `vi`, I assume that you already know `vi` command mode well enough to write a command for the actual operation you want to perform, and thus that the only question is about `ex` command-line usage.

Comment: Now I have updated my question. Please see and suggest.

Comment: I have tried your suggested code block, but it is not working. I am working with korn shell.

Comment: Which vendor's implementation of `ex`? Mine is tested with the BSD-derived version Apple ships. Also, as a rule, you need to give better error reports than "not working". Not working *how*? No changes to the file? An error message? If so, what message? Etc.

Comment: @user286009, ...I also added an implementation tested against GNU's `ex`.

Comment: scsps041:/home/selfadm$ ./sc.sh
:q
scsps041:/home/selfadm$

Comment: scsps041:/home/adm$ ./sc.sh
:q
scsps041:/home/adm$ (This is the problem.  I don't know which vendors implementation is this. The file remain unchanged)

Comment: If you don't know the vendor -- do you know your operating system? Or we can start talking tools other than `vi` -- because, as I said before, using `vi` doesn't buy you anything in terms of atomicity/safety around concurrent access.

Comment: Is there no way other than it? I am running Solaris.

Comment: Somehow, I'm not surprised -- as much cutting-edge work as they do in kernel space, Sun has always been one of the last OS vendors to bring their userspace tools in line with the modern world (witness their `/bin/sh` being 1970s-era Bourne rather than POSIX sh).

Comment: I've given you an option that doesn't use `vi` or `ex` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an answer as

```
vi my_file <@ >/dev/null 2>&1
iF<ESC>
:wq
@
```

With  the escape sequence of ESC, what you can enter by typing CTRL-V ESC
The newline before :wq is not needed, but makes this rubbish a little bit easier to read.

I am afraid this solution will work most of the time, until some logging is gone.
vi makes a working copy of the file, edits the working copy and writes back that copy. Changes during the edit will not be seen. You can check this by opening the same file with vi in two windows. Or even in one window:

```
vi testfile <@ >/dev/null 2>&1
iFirstline
Second Line<ESC>
:r !date
:w
:! echo This line will be gone >> testfile
:wq
@
```

Now check the testfile.